# How to iterate through a specific key in a map containing vector as value?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

How to iterate through the contents of map["a"] to retrieve `call` and `call1` ?

```
std::vector<std::string> point
std::map<std::string, point> alloc

map["a"] = call, call1
map["i"] = call
```

I have tried using `for` loop using `map` iterator and inside that `for` loop another `for` loop on the vector and then checking whether the value of map iterator map equals "a" but keep getting an error.

Comment: I fear you have to be more specific than that.

Comment: Who ever changed the code thanks. I had typed that but was using mobile version so it must have changed to code

Comment: I think I explained the answer below. Check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding some syntax and of the programming language and the semantics of the standard library containers a little bit. I will explain what I think you are doing wrong.

First thing is that you have a vector of `string` objects called `point`, this is an **object** not a **type**. An object is a variable of a type, for example

```
string name = "curious";
```

Here name is an object of type/class `string`, so you cannot type in `point` as the template parameter to the `map`, you have to type in a type. So that should be a `string`.

Second thing is that you are using the comma operator, I am not sure if you knew that you were doing that.  The comma operator works as follows

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <string>
using std::string;

int main() {
    cout << ("Hello", "World") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

^ this will generate a compiler error because the "Hello" is not used but the point is that the comma operator evaluates the first part of the expression and then returns the thing on the right; so this will print

```
World
```

Third thing is how you iterate through the map. When you iterate through a `std::map` in C++ you are actually iterating through a series of `std::pair`s so the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <map>
using std::map;

int main() {
    map<string, int> map_string_int {{"curious", 1}, {"op", 2}};

    for (auto iter = map_string_int.begin(); iter != map_string_int.end();
            ++iter) {
        cout << iter->first << " : " << iter->second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

will produce the following output

```
curious : 1
op : 2
```

the keys will be ordered alphabetically because they are stored in a binary search tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)

Now I think you wanted to have a map from `string` objects to `vector`s, so you would structure your code as such

```
std::vector<string> point
std::map<string, std::vector<string>> alloc;

alloc["a"] = {"call", "call1"};
alloc["i"] = {"call"};
```

and you would iterate through this like so

```
for (auto iter = alloc.begin(); iter != alloc.end(); ++iter) {
    cout << iter->first << " : " << iter->second << endl;
}
```

You would iterate through `alloc["a"]` like so

```
// sanity check
assert(alloc.find("a") != alloc.end());
for (auto iter = alloc["a"].begin(); iter != alloc["a"].end(); ++iter) {
        cout << *iter << endl;
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: I actually want only the contents of alloc["a"]. How get that specifically ?

Comment: Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean `std::multimap` instead of `std::map`, based on your use case (multiple values under the same key). It's in the same `<map>` header.

```
std::multimap<std::string, int> map;
map.insert(std::make_pair("first", 123));
map.insert(std::make_pair("first", 456));

auto result = map.equal_range("first");
for (auto it = result.first; it != result.second; ++it)
    std::cout << " " << it->second;
```

Reference: [std::multimap::equal_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want if I understand correctly.

```
std::vector<string> point = { "Hello", "World" };
std::map<std::string, decltype(point)> my_map;

//if you dont wan't to use decltype (or cant):
//std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> my_map;

my_map["A"] = point;
my_map["B"] = { "Something", "Else" };

//this will iterate only trought my_map["A"]
for (const auto &vector_val : my_map["A"])
    std::cout << vector_val << std::endl;

//this will iterate trought the whole map
for (const auto &map_pair : my_map)
{       
    std::cout << "map: " << map_pair.first << std::endl;

    for (const auto &vector_val : map_pair.second)
        std::cout << vector_val << std::endl;

    std::cout << "---------------------------------" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about knowing what is more suitable in such situations i.e multimap or map_of_vectors .
If sequencially someone want to iterate vector associated to a particular/all keys in map
what will be more efficient/optimal.

```
map<string ,vector<string>> mp;
// initialize your map...
for(auto itr=mp.begin(); itr!=mp.end() ;itr++)
   for(auto itr2=itr->second.begin(); itr2!=itr->second.end() ;itr2++)
      cout<<*itr2
```

for particular key just change first loop as stated down

```
auto itr=mp.find(key);
```